# Botman typesAndWaits adds initial delay

Tags: chatbot

When I use `typesAndWaits` method with 2 seconds delay, I have to wait for 2 seconds in order to typing indicator display and when it is displayed I need to wait for another 2 seconds to display message.
I'm using BotMan chatbot service.

Here is my code:

```
$botman->hears('test', function (BotMan $bot) {
    $bot->typesAndWaits(2);
    $bot->reply('Prvo upiši svoje ime i prezime, i pritisnite SEND');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the BotMan.php file, go to line 583 and replace

```
sleep($seconds);
```

With

```
usleep($seconds * 1000000);
```

It should work fine then...